# Writing arbitrary attributes on a model is deprecated. (Multiple belongs_to on model)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have multiple `belongs_to` relationships to the same model. Modeling messages between two users as follows (in the `Message` model):

```
  belongs_to :to, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'to_id'
  belongs_to :from, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'from_id'

  attr_accessible :to, :from # ...
```

The corresponding `has_many` calls are in the `User` model.  Everything works in the spec and the console as I need it to, with the exception of the following deprecation warning (for both `from_id` and `to_id`):

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: You're trying to create an attribute `from_id'. Writing arbitrary attributes on a model is deprecated. Please just use `attr_writer`
```

The relevant spec follows:

```
  it "can associate users" do
    User.delete(:all)
    ufrom = FactoryGirl.create(:DrKevorkian)
    ufrom.save!
    uto = FactoryGirl.create(:JohnSmith)
    uto.save!

    m = Message.new
    m.from = ufrom   # <-- Warning here
    m.to = uto       # <-- Warning here
    m.save

    m.from.id.should == ufrom.id
    m.to.id.should == uto.id

  end
```

It seems to me the warning is happening as a result of the `belongs_to` association -- is there a cleaner/better way to do this?

Thanks very much.

Comment: One minor thought.  From the Rails docs on "belongs_to": By default this [foreign_key] is guessed to be the name of the association with an “_id” suffix.  So the two :foreign_key options on your model are redundant.

Comment: Yes, what's up with the 14%?

Comment: I don't know what's up with the 14%.  Probably it's a combination of laziness and being an eclectic jerk who's moved on to Java by the time someone sees my Rails question (for example).  But on the other hand, are you saying you've looked through all my questions and you know that the percentage with good answers is significantly higher than that?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

My experience is that you get this warning if you forgot to run `rake db:migrate` and `rake db:test:prepare` after changing your schema.

Comment: Saved me a big headache, thanks! Forgot to test:prepare after I changed schema.